# How to dynamically add fields and methods to a class during runtime by reading a XML configuration?

Tags: java, class, runtime

For making all fields in Java Bean can be configurable, I want to dynamically fields and methods which from reading XML configuration to a basic Java class during runtime. Is there a way to  do this? And if there is a simple sample can be offered here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go for the proxy pattern,, It will exactly solve your requirement(if you know all the possible values that can be given in XML). Also If not,, Then try CGLIB .

Comment: Assuming we do not know what fields would be configured in it.

Comment: Frankly I don't think you are getting me correctly, If you have the XML you must be knowing its DTDs(in PI) I feel, You don't need to know the exact values, But all the possible values that can be there for a particular element of the XML , Then you can easily create an XML parser and develop your workFlow controller correspondingly, ie; if (val1) call func1 if (val2) call func2,, and the reusable  code would be put in some commonly accessible func of the target class. Thats about the Proxy Objects(based on tags).For CGLIB, Follow http://markbramnik.blogspot.com/2010/04/cglib-introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

java is not dynamically language on runtime.

but you can use ASM framework ( http://asm.ow2.org/ ).